# get value javascript from Session variable and convert into date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

i am trying to get value from Session Variable in javascript
and want to convert into time format

i have tried is

```
function SessionTime() {

    var someSessionVariable = new Date('<%= Session["LogInTime"].ToString() %>'); //Date.parseDate(@Session["LogInTime"],"dd/MM/yyyy");  
    alert(someSessionVariable);
    document.getElementById("SessionTime").innerHTML = someSessionVariable.toLocaleTimeString();
    window.setTimeout("SessionTime()", 1000); // Here 1000(milliseconds) means one 1 Sec  
}
```

i am getting invalid date on `alert(someSessionVariable);`

**all i wanted to do is**

show a user a elapsed time from the time of login which i am getting in:

```
<%= Session["LogInTime"].ToString() %>
```

please help!!!

Comment: what is the format of the date in session?

Comment: at present format is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" but is picks up format of client machine

Comment: use YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss tt format

Comment: i dont know what format will be on clients machine it picks up from client machine how do i convert it?

Comment: set the format from the server, why are you involving clients machine for date format?

Comment: ok i did that but issue is to show time elapsed

Comment: look at this fiddle, i hope it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/cckSj/5/